# How to change the path of config-overrides from root directory while using react-app-rewired?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, command-line-arguments, react-app-rewired

so I am using react-app-rewired to change the `webpack.config`, but I want to keep my `config-override` directory inside `./scripts/`. but I don't know how to do that.

This how I am run the command:

```
const react_app_rewired_start = 'npx react-app-rewired start';

if (process.env.ALLOW_LOGS === "YES") {
  // Execute the npm command
  spawn(react_app_rewired_start, { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });
}
```

current location looks like this ./config-overrides and i want it to like ./scripts/config-overrides

`spawn(`${react_app_rewired_start} -- --config-overrides=../../scripts/config-overrides/index.js`, { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });`

I tried passing path as an argument but this is not working.